# Dynamically access types from an `import * as` in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a `models.ts` like so:

```
class Foo {
    name?: string;
}

type FooDocument = { name: string };

export { Foo, FooDocument };
```

Where each "Document" of a class type has the serialized interface (no Functions/getters, etc)

Now when I import the models in a different file, I seem to be unable to access those types by name?

```
import * as models from './models'

// Works!
type A = models.FooDocument  

// No worky
type B = models['FooDocument'] // Cannot use 'models' as a type ts(2709)

// Still no worky :(
type C = typeof models['FooDocument'] // Property 'FooDocument' does not exist on type 'typeof import('./models')' ts(2339)
```

Is this just a limitation of Typescript or am I doing something wrong?

For convenience, I made a CodeSandbox with this setup:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-dijkstra-3u0fq?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why I can't just use dot syntax... I have an ORM adapter for various CRUD methods that I'd like to statically type using the name of the Model and the associated Document interface. Using conditional mapped types I am able to generate the correct associations, but I don't seem to be able to get these exported types out of the `import * as` variable.

Comment: This is *really* odd. Your final error looks like TypeScript is giving the `typeof` operator higher precedence than the `[` (computed member access) operator, which is contrary to the ES spec as far as I can see from a quick Google search.

Comment: Typescript's `typeof` operator, when used in a type context rather than in an expression, is not part of the ES spec at all.

Comment: Well I guess it's some consolation that others find this odd as well!